# I need some help , can anybody explain the Custom sorting code below ; how exactly the code blocks are working?

Tags: python, string, sorting, dictionary

please read the code first; i am trying to get familiar with custom sorting so I need help understanding how 'eksge' is sorted into 'geeks' and what's happening inside def sortbypattern function, how 'g' is made to appear first then followed by 'e' ,'e' ,'k' ,'s'; can anyone explain me the algorithm and a dry run

```
def sortbyPattern(pat, str):
  
    priority = list(pat)
  
    # Create a dictionary to store priority of each character
    myDict = { priority[i] : i for i in range(len(priority))}
  
    str = list(str)
  
    # Pass lambda function as key in sort function
    str.sort( key = lambda ele : myDict[ele])
  
    # Reverse the string using reverse()
    str.reverse()
  
    new_str = ''.join(str)
    return new_str
  
  
if __name__=='__main__':
    pat = "asbcklfdmegnot"
    str =  "eksge"
    new_str = sortbyPattern(pat, str)
    print(new_str)
```

Output : geeks

Comment: What, *exactly* do you not understand?

Comment: As an aside, you really should never name a variable `str`

Comment: I think if you print the value of myDict then review the documentation around a list's sort() method, you'll figure it out

Comment: ill try that, this code is actually from geeksforgeeks, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sorting-string-using-order-defined-by-another-string/ . my whole point is , we all know the conventional sorting methods right? im searching online for a way to sort in a custom manner . for example, lets say my name is Parker . and i give a string "rkearp" . i need the program to sort it or rearrange that string into Parker. do u have any ideas ? other than what i already listed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sortbyPattern` function takes `pattern` and the `string` to be sorted as parameters. The `pattern` is working as a priority list here. The less the index number the lower the priority.

Inside the function, the `priority` is a list of the characters in the `pattern`. The pattern given is `asbcklfdmegnot`. If you print `priority`, you'll get:

```
['a', 's', 'b', 'c', 'k', 'l', 'f', 'd', 'm', 'e', 'g', 'n', 'o', 't']
```

So, as the lower the index, the lower the priority, we can make a dict having priority score similar to their corresponding index. That is what done in the line `myDict = { priority[i] : i for i in range(len(priority))}`. The dict looks like this:

```
{'a': 0, 's': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'k': 4, 'l': 5, 'f': 6, 'd': 7, 'm': 8, 'e': 9, 'g': 10, 'n': 11, 'o': 12, 't': 13}
```

Now, `str = list(str)` is called to make a list of characters inside the input `str` variable, `eksge`. Then `str.sort( key = lambda ele : myDict[ele])` is applied. This basically sorted the `str` based on the value of each character in `str` in the dict `myDict`. So the `str` is sorted in ascending order based on the value of each character it got from `myDict`. In this situation, we got in `str`:

```
['s', 'k', 'e', 'e', 'g']
```

Finally, `str.reverse()` made the `str` reversed, hence `str` in desired order.

Point to be noted, if you had done a `reverse=True` in the sort parameter, you wouldn't need to call that `str.reverse()`

Comment: Thanks a ton for explaining the flow and process of execution entirely <3. I understand this code a lot better now.

Comment: @Barry99 If this answers your question, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the use of such a function may be, but it's rather simple:

- `pat`, then `priority` (which by the way is a totally useless step), and finally `myDict` specify the expected ordering of the chars
- `sort` sorts your string comparing each char based on the priority from `myDict` instead of a standard alphabetical ordering

Comment: yes, but I want to know how myDict is giving 'g' first priority then two e's then a k and s . I tried custom sort my own name from a bunch of jumbled alphabets but it's not working

Comment: As you probably can see now thanks to the detailed answer by devReddit, this custom sort will correctly work on "Barry" with any jumbled alphabet where 'y' precedes 'r' which precedes 'a' which precedes 'b': e.g. "sktygfrqawvbn" will do

Comment: Yes, it Worked. I understand a lot better now. Thanks